# Delphi: How to remove subclasses in reverse order?

Tags: delphi, themes, subclassing, delphi-5, dwm

Mike Lischke's `TThemeServices` subclasses `Application.Handle`, so that it can receive broadcast notifications from Windows (i.e. `WM_THEMECHANGED`) when theming changes.

It subclasses the `Application` object's window:

```
FWindowHandle := Application.Handle;
if FWindowHandle <> 0 then
begin
 // If a window handle is given then subclass the window to get notified about theme changes.
 {$ifdef COMPILER_6_UP}
    FObjectInstance := Classes.MakeObjectInstance(WindowProc);
 {$else}
    FObjectInstance := MakeObjectInstance(WindowProc);
 {$endif COMPILER_6_UP}
 FDefWindowProc := Pointer(GetWindowLong(FWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC));
 SetWindowLong(FWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(FObjectInstance));
end;
```

The subclassed window procdure then does, as it's supposed to, `WM_DESTROY` message, remove it's subclass, and then pass the `WM_DESTROY` message on:

```
procedure TThemeServices.WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
     WM_THEMECHANGED:
        begin
               [...snip...]
        end;
     WM_DESTROY:
        begin
          // If we are connected to a window then we have to listen to its destruction.
          SetWindowLong(FWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(FDefWindowProc));
          {$ifdef COMPILER_6_UP}
             Classes.FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
          {$else}
             FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
          {$endif COMPILER_6_UP}
          FObjectInstance := nil;
        end;
  end;

  with Message do
     Result := CallWindowProc(FDefWindowProc, FWindowHandle, Msg, WParam, LParam);
end;
```

The `TThemeServices` object is a singleton, destroyed during unit finalization:

```
initialization
finalization
  InternalThemeServices.Free;
end.
```

And that all works well - as long as TThemeServices is the only guy who ever subclasses the Application's handle.

i have a similar singleton library, that also wants to hook `Application.Handle` so i can receive broadcasts:

```
procedure TDesktopWindowManager.WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
case Message.Msg of
WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED: ...
WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED: ...
WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED: ...
WM_DESTROY:
    begin
        // If we are connected to a window then we have to listen to its destruction.
        SetWindowLong(FWindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(FDefWindowProc));
        {$ifdef COMPILER_6_UP}
        Classes.FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
        {$else}
        FreeObjectInstance(FObjectInstance);
        {$endif COMPILER_6_UP}
        FObjectInstance := nil;
    end;
end;

with Message do
    Result := CallWindowProc(FDefWindowProc, FWindowHandle, Msg, WParam, LParam);
```

And *my* singleton is similarly removed when the unit finalizes:

```
initialization
   ...
finalization
    InternalDwmServices.Free;
end.
```

---

Now we come to the problem. i can't guarantee the order in which someone might choose to access `ThemeServices` or `DWM`, each of which apply their subclass. Nor can i know the order in which Delphi will finalize units.

The subclasses are being removed in the wrong order, and there is a crash on application close.

How to fix? How can i [ensure that i keep my subclassing method around long enough until the *other* guy is done](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx) after me is done? (i don't want to leak memory, after all)

### See also

- [Raymond Chen: Safer Subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx)
- [MSDN: Using Window Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Raymond Chen: When the normal window destruction messages are thrown for a loop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/27/443824.aspx)

---

**Update:** i see Delphi 7 solves the bug by rewriting `TApplication`. ><

```
procedure TApplication.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
...
begin
   ...
   with Message do
      case Msg of
      ...
      WM_THEMECHANGED:
          if ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled then
              ThemeServices.ApplyThemeChange;
      ...
   end;
   ...
end;
```

**Grrrr**

In other words: trying to subclass TApplication was a bug, that Borland fixed when they adopted Mike's `TThemeManager`.

That very well may mean that there is no way to remove subclasses on `TApplication` in reverse order. Someone put that in the form of an answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: Delphi 7's theme code is based on Mike Lischke's code. But of course, since they have the source, then there's no need for them to subclass. Is there a good reason why you can't use a modern Delphi?

Comment: I don't agree at all that subclassing TApplication, as Mike did in his XP theme manager, was a bug. What else could he have done? What's more I regard that code as one of the greatest works of coding I've ever come across. In fact that's still one of the primary references for themed painting. Although there were some minor bugs they were few and far between and hardly surprising considering the complexity of what he was attempting. So, I'm sticking up for Mike, in response to your "Grrrr"!!

Comment: i didn't mean to imply that subclassing `TApplication` was a bug - only that how he did it is buggy (it assumes nobody else before him subclassed TApplication, and that nobody else after him will either)

Comment: Why the delphi-t tag? What is delphi-t?

Comment: @Jørn. Whoops. "T" is one key short of "5". Fixed the tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to call [`SetWindowSubclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102%28VS.85%29.aspx), as the article you linked to advises. But that only works if everyone uses the same API, so patch Theme Manager to use the same technique. The API was introduced in Windows XP, so there's no danger that it's not available on the systems where it would be needed.

There should be no problem with patching Theme Manager. It's designed to support Windows XP, which Microsoft doesn't support anymore, and to support Delphi 4 through 6, which Borland doesn't support anymore. Since development has ceased on all relevant products, it is safe for you to fork the Theme Manager project without risk of falling behind due to future updates.

You're not really introducing a dependency. Rather, you're fixing a bug that's only present when both window-appearance libraries are in use at the same time. Users of your library don't need to have Theme Manager for yours to work, but if they wish to use both, they need to use Theme Manager with your patches applied. There should be little objection to that since they already have the base version, so it's not like they'd be installing an entirely new library. They'd just be applying a patch and recompiling.

Comment: The issue i still can't figure out, even when using SetWindowSubClass, is what to do when i want to unregister. The documentation doesn't mention it (the documentation doesn't mention much of anything - even the reason it exists) - but do i still have to keep my subclassing object around - as Raymond points out.

Comment: And some customers still use Windows 2000; so i'd would also introduce crashes

Comment: @Ian Themes and Dwm don't exist on Win2k either. So you wouldn't be calling this API when run on Win2k.

Comment: @David That's a excellent point; i never thought of it that way. Although the library does handle DWM not being available, the first thing it does on `Create` is hook the window. i can just *not* hook the window if `SetWindowSublcass` isn't available - or even better: not hook if DWM isn't available.

Comment: @Ian @Rob SetWindowSubClass is certainly a good solution, but it's much more invasive than the solution that I offered. You objected to that because you'd have to change Mike Lischke's code, but you'll need to make a lot more changes to use SetWindowSubClass. Not that it's particularly hard to do so, but I just thought I would point that out.

Comment: @Ian, MSDN has an overview about [subclassing windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183.aspx), where it explains, "ComCtl32.dll version 6 supplied with Windows XP contains four functions that make creating subclasses easier and eliminate the disadvantages previously discussed." To unregister, just call `RemoveWindowSubclass`. Under the hood, I suspect `SetWindowSubclass` subclasses in the traditional way, but then manages it own list of subclasses where it's safe to remove from the middle. Call `DefSubclassProc` instead of directly calling the previous window proc.

Comment: @Rob I hope you don't take offence to my last comment, I don't mean to knock what you wrote and I did give you an up-vote!

Comment: Oh damn...i realized that SetWindowSubclass is in `CommCtrl32.dll` version 6. The only way i get version 6 is by manifesting my application to opt into version 6. If i do that i will get version 6 of the common controls. i'm using Delphi 5, which used the common controls improperly, which causes crashes. Mike tried to write `TThemeManager` to patch all Borland's wrappers- but there's still bugs it can't fix. So i can't use that :(

Comment: @ian looks like a delphi upgrade is needed

Comment: @Ian: If you still care, the `SetWindowSubclass` class of functions still exist in older versions of CommCtrl32.dll, they're just exported by ordinal only. You have to do some digging, but you can use them if you really want to. [See here for details](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/HookXP/), albeit in VB 6-speak.

Comment: Documentation says SetWindowSubclass is in Comctl32 version 5.8.

Comment: @Cody Gray, @Rob Kennedy. You're right. Although, Rob, it does say minimum supported OS is XP/2003, while i have to support 2000. But a random 2000 machine i looked at has 5.81. So i'm sort of in a no-mans-land, where i can't officially use it or depend on it - but i might be able to use and depend on it.

Comment: But Ian, I thought we already established that Windows 2000 support doesn't really matter — at least for your purposes — because the theme- and DWM-related messages you want to intercept won't be sent. That OS supports neither themes nor DWM.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than subclassing the TApplication window, perhaps you can use AllocateHWnd() instead to receive the same broadcasts separately, since it is a top-level window of its own.

Comment: Hmmmmm. i never thought of that. Actually i had, but i didn't think some random message loop i setup would count.

Comment: If you call AllocateHWND() in the context of the main thread, it will use the main message loop, just as TApplication's window does.  A thread content can run multiple top-level windows.

Comment: Wait, will it use the main message loop code, or will it literally use the main message loop? Cause while the former is leveraging code, the latter means i'll be getting messages for any messages posted to any window in my application. i would just want messages being sent to *my* `AllocateHwnd` window.

Comment: An HWND is tied to the thread context that creates it. That thread needs a message queue and message processing loop. If you call AllocateHWnd() in the main thread context, its HWND will use the main thread's existing message queue and message loop (if you call AllocateHWnd() in a worker thread - which is not technically safe - then you have to implement your own message queue/loop in that thread). In that situation, the HWND will only receive messages that are explicitally posted/sent to it, and also top-level broadcasts. HWNDs do not receive messages belonging to other HWNDs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do the following:

- Put a reference to ThemeServices in the initialization section of ThemeSrv.pas.
- Put a reference to DwmServices in the initialization section of DwmSrv.pas (I'm guess the name of your unit).

Since units are finalised in reverse order from the order of initialisation, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Can't really change other people's units; or want to take a dependancy between them.

Comment: @Ian I can't imagine Mike would mind you doing that. I know I've modified his code to fix bugs in it. Finally I don't know what you mean about taking a dependency on other units. Your entire problem is one of dependencies.

Comment: @Ian Regarding your comment, "Can't really change other people's units", you appear to have no qualms about copying the code from them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the ApplicationEvents and be done with it. No need to messing around with subclassing. 
The other way is to create only one subclass and create multi-notify events and subscribe as many as you wish.

Cheers

Comment: Theme Manager supports Delphi version 4 through 6. `TApplicationEvents` is not available in all those versions. Besides, the `OnMessage` event gets called for *all* messages posted to *any* window in the application, whereas the desire is to only intercept the messages aimed at the single application window. Furthermore, `OnMessage` doesn't see *sent* messages, only *posted* messages.