# Delphi XE2 - Inheriting class not calling base class' constructor...?

Tags: delphi, class, inheritance

When creating a class that inherits from another class, shouldn't it be true that when the derived class is created the base classes's constructor is called?

```
Type
  TBase = Class
    constructor xMain;
  End;
  TDerived  = Class(TBase)
    constructor xMain;
  End;

constructor TBase.xMain;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'TBase','TBase',0);
end;

constructor TDerived.xMain;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'TDerived','TDerived',0);
end;


Var
  xTClass:TDerived;
begin
  xTClass := TDerived.xMain;
end.
```

I thought this should result in a MessageBox displaying "TBase" and then "TDerived". Yet, this is not the case. When the above code is ran it only results in one MessageBox displaying "TDerived".

Comment: You should name constructors Create even if the language itself does not force you to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
constructor TDerived.xMain;
begin
  inherited;
  MessageBox(0,'TDerived','TDerived',0);
end;
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thanks. Will accept in few mins when it lets me.

Answer (score 6):

add inherited in TDerived.xMain; otherwise the code from ancestor will not be called;

```
begin
  inherited;//call the ancestor TBase.xMain
  MessageBox(0,'TDerived','TDerived',0);
end;
```

Also this question will help you understand inherited reserved word:

[Delphi: How to call inherited inherited ancestor on a virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662744/delphi-how-to-call-inherited-inherited-ancestor)

another good resource is http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Inherited

Comment: You also may want/need to call inherited for overridden methods - IF you want to perform the ancestor methods functionality and then add to it.